# Commonqt Not Working Using Clozure CL on OS X Lion

Tags: qt, osx-lion, common-lisp, ccl, quicklisp

I wanted to use Commonqt using Clozure CL on OS X Lion.

But it was not working...

### Commonqt

> Commonqt is a Common Lisp binding to the smoke library for Qt.
>
> http://common-lisp.net/project/commonqt/

### My setting is that

> OS X Lion 10.7.4
>
> Xcode 4.3.3
>
> Clozure CL version 1.8
>
> qt 4.8.2 (git clone git://gitorious.org/qt/qt.git) "./configure && make install && make"
>
> smoke
>
> - somkegen (git clone git://anongit.kde.org/smokegen) "cmake . && make install"
> - smokeqt (git clone git://anongit.kde.org/smokeqt) "cmake . && make install"
>
> quicklisp
>
> - local-projects commonqt (git clone git://gitorious.org/commonqt/commonqt.git) "qmake && make clean && make"
>
> cf: http://kvardek-du.kerno.org/2011/12/setting-up-commonqt-on-osx.html

### qt.asd(in Commonqt)

```
(defmethod output-files ((operation compile-op) (c cpp->so))   (values
    (loop for filename in '("libcommonqt.so" "libcommonqt.so.1"
                            "libcommonqt.so.1.0" "libcommonqt.so.1.0.0")
          collect (merge-pathnames filename (component-pathname c)))
    ;; libcommonqt.so* files are never moved to separate FASL directory
    t))
```

so I was changed (so -> dylib) that

```
(defmethod output-files ((operation compile-op) (c cpp->so))   (values
    (loop for filename in '("libcommonqt.dylib" "libcommonqt.1.dylib"
                            "libcommonqt.1.0.dylib" "libcommonqt.1.0.0.dylib")
          collect (merge-pathnames filename (component-pathname c)))
    ;; libcommonqt.so* files are never moved to separate FASL directory
    t))
```

But Error has Occurred. For example

Source code

http://pleasegodno.wordpress.com/common-lisp-tutorials/common-lisp-gui-programming-with-commonqt/2-classes-and-methods/

```
? (main)
MAIN
? > Error: Unable to load foreign library (LIBCOMMONQT.DYLIB-31136).
>          Error opening shared library /Users/jk/.quicklisp/local-projects/commonqt/libcommonqt.dylib : dlopen(/Users/jk/.quicklisp/local-projects/commonqt/libcommonqt.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>           /Users/jk/.quicklisp/local-projects/commonqt/libcommonqt.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture.
> While executing: CFFI::FL-ERROR, in process listener(1).
> Type :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> Type :? for other options.
1 >
```

Is this My wrong Setting? or Is Commonqt's source not working using Clozure Cl on OS X Lion?

Next, what should I do?

### user1234192's advice: ccl -> ccl64

I retry it.

```
> (qt-conv:main)
2012-07-12 21:46:11.630 dx86cl64[93621:c403] *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-833.25/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:324
2012-07-12 21:46:11.631 dx86cl64[93621:c403] +[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.
2012-07-12 21:46:11.633 dx86cl64[93621:c403] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dc49f56 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9600dd5e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dc49d8a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8de4671f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 169
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8ddb595f +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 144
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8b15a0ef -[NSApplication run] + 596
    6   QtGui                               0x000000000346cc60 _ZN19QEventDispatcherMac13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 840
    7   QtCore                              0x0000000004122838 _ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 394
    8   QtCore                              0x0000000004125b0b _ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv + 175
    9   libsmokeqtgui.dylib                 0x00000000043718e1 _ZN12__smokeqtgui14x_QApplication4x_84EPN5Smoke9StackItemE + 17
    10  libsmokeqtgui.dylib                 0x00000000043579d8 _ZN12__smokeqtgui18xcall_QApplicationEsPvPN5Smoke9StackItemE + 1304
    11  dx86cl64                            0x000000000001b0db SPffcall + 99
    12  ???                                 0x0000000001219328 0x0 + 18977576
)
2012-07-12 21:46:11.634 dx86cl64[93621:c403] *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-833.25/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:324
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

Unhandled exception 10 at 0x0, context->regs at #xb029af30
Exception occurred while executing foreign code
received signal 10; faulting address: 0x0
? for help
[93621] Clozure CL kernel debugger: help
[93621] Clozure CL kernel debugger: [93621] Clozure CL kernel debugger: [93621] Clozure CL kernel debugger: Segmentation fault: 11
```

Answer (score 3):

http://kvardek-du.kerno.org/2011/12/setting-up-commonqt-on-osx.html

I was success on clozure cl(Lion)

and...your error message.."libcommonqt.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture"

maybe..your ccl and libcommonqt.dylib are differently architecture.

if your ccl is x86(32bit) , libcommonqt.dylib must x86.

if your ccl is x8664(64bit), libcommonqt.dylib must x8664...

I recommend 64-bit.

My English is very ugly.  sorry.......

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Your advice is correct. I was not using ccl64... So I change ccl64 and retry.
But

2012-07-12 21:46:11.634 dx86cl64[93621:c403] *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /SourceCache/Foundation/Foundation-833.25/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:324
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.
Unhandled exception 10 at 0x0, context->regs at #xb029af30
Exception occurred while executing foreign code

Answer (score 0):

try

(ql:quickload :trivial-main-thread)
(trivial-main-thread:call-in-main-thread #'qt-conv:main)